Incidence rates from manual calculation differs from that obtained from the estimated marginal means of a poisson regression

Poisson Regression

I have done a poisson regression where the data is individual-level data, the dependent variable, event is 1 if individual had the event or 0 if the individual did not have the event. The independent variable, positive_culture_group  is the 3 groups that I am trying to make comparison (Aerobic, Blood and Aerobic & Blood). I have an offset, which is the log of the time_to_event. Then, I did the estimated marginal means using emmeans::emmeans function to calculate the incidence rate. This is the code:
model <- glm(event ~ positive_culture_group + offset(log(time_to_event/365.25)),
data = df, family = "poisson")
emmeans::emmeans(model, ~ positive_culture_group, type = "response", offset = log(100000)) 

The results:
 positive_culture_group  rate   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Aerobic                 8500 1578 Inf      5907     12232
 Blood                  46353 4440 Inf     38419     55925
 Aerobic & Blood        10449 1975 Inf      7215     15134

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 


Manual Calculation

This is the code that I have used

df <- df %>% filter(positive_culture_group == "Aerobic") # Change accordingly for Blood and Aerobic & Blood

# Number of events
new_cases <- sum(df$event == 1)

# Total person-years involved
person_years <- sum(df$time_to_event)/365.25

# Calculate incidence rate
incidence_rate <- (new_cases / person_years) * 100000  # Convert to per 100,000 person-years

# Exact Poisson method to calculate CI
lower_bound <- qpois(0.025, lambda = new_cases) / person_years * 100000
upper_bound <- qpois(0.975, lambda = new_cases) / person_years * 100000

The results are
Aerobic
Incidence Rate of CRC: 879.3436 per 100,000 person-years
95% CI (Lower Bound): 0
95% CI (Upper Bound): 2051.802

Blood   
Incidence Rate of CRC: 2126.266 per 100,000 person-years
95% CI (Lower Bound): 425.2532
95% CI (Upper Bound): 4252.532

Aerobic & Blood 
Incidence Rate of CRC: 746.3678 per 100,000 person-years
95% CI (Lower Bound): 0
95% CI (Upper Bound): 1865.919

How do I continue using poisson regression and try to obtain the same values as the manual collection?

Is the goal for the GLM to match your manual calculations, or vice versa? The former should be easy enough (just run a separate model for each of the positive_culture_group), I don't think the latter is really feasible.

Ideally I want GLM to produce the same results as my manual calculations. Because ultimately, I do want the IRR and the p-values associated with it. Do you meant to run model <- glm(event ~ 1,              offset = log(time_to_event/365.25),              data = df, family = "poisson"); emmeans::emmeans(model, ~1, type = "response") because this does not work.

Then I feel you have it backwards, you can get the GLM to match your manual calculation if you model each group separately (e.g. use subset(df, positive_culture_group=="Aerobic") for the first estimate) and align the approximations (emmeans uses Wald intervals). That will not bring you any closer to a group comparison however. To me it seems preferable to get all your estimates from the GLM you currently have, with all groups in it.

You are right that in this particular case the two approaches should give the exact same results (with some possible small differences in the confidence intervals). You had the wrong formula for the standard error/confidence limits in your manual calculation, but after tidying up your code, I got matching results for the two approaches. If you don't get those, I would double-check that you've got the latest versions of the packages.
E.g. this approximately gives your manual results, but with the correct approximate asymptotic confidence intervals (you can't rpois for those, that gives the sampling variability, not the confidence limits):
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)

df <- tibble(positive_culture_group = c("Aerobic", "Blood", "Aerobic & Blood"),
             event = c(879, 2126, 746),
             time_to_event = 100000*365.25)

# Manual calculation
df %>%
  group_by(positive_culture_group) %>%
  summarize(evts = sum(event),
            py = sum(time_to_event/365.25),
            evts_per_100kpy = evts/py*100000,
            log_stderr = 1/sqrt(evts),
            lcl = exp(log(evts_per_100kpy) - qnorm(0.975)*log_stderr),
            ucl = exp(log(evts_per_100kpy) + qnorm(0.975)*log_stderr))

We get the exact same thing using a model:
# Using a model
model <- glm(event ~ 0 + positive_culture_group + offset(log(time_to_event/365.25)),
             data = df, 
             family = poisson(link="log"))

# Basic approach that works here if we use a formula with 0 + ...
coefficients(model) %>%
  exp() %>%
  (\(x) x*100000)()

# More general
model %>%
  emmeans(~ positive_culture_group, type = "response", offset = log(100000)) 

And using emmeans it doesn't really matter whether you use the syntax with 0+... or 1+...:
# Using a model v2 (same as event ~ positive_culture_group...)
model2 <- glm(event ~ 1 + positive_culture_group + offset(log(time_to_event/365.25)),
             data = df, 
             family = poisson(link="log"))
model2 %>%
  emmeans(~ positive_culture_group, type = "response", offset = log(100000)) 

Extra example showing individual patient data and summed up aggregate data give identical inference
It is from a theoretical perspective clear that individual patient data (IPD) and summed up aggregate data will give identical inference, because the summed up number by group are the sufficient statistics. Also, the Poisson likelihood (for IPD or aggregate data) with the appropriate offset results in the same (log-)likelihood (+- irrelevant factors) as an exponential time-to-event.
This is illustrated below (the only differences are the flipped sign because of the parameterization used by survreg and different AIC etc. values due to different sample sizes used by the procedures):
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

example <- tibble(t = c(10, 5, 5, 17, 18, 2, 5, 3, 8, 12, 22, 33, 2, 5),
                  evt = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                  grp = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)))

example %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(evt=sum(evt),
            t=sum(t),
            .group="drop") %>%
  glm(data=., 
      formula=evt ~ 0 + grp + offset(log(t)),
      family=poisson(link="log"))

example %>%
  glm(data=., 
      formula=evt ~ 0 + grp + offset(log(t)),
      family=poisson(link="log"))

example %>%
  survival::survreg(data=., 
      formula=survival::Surv(time=t, event=evt) ~ 0 + grp, 
      dist = "exponential")
```


Thanks. Besides the incorrect method for calculating confidence interval, the difference in estimates was due to using individual-level data (Y=0/1) instead of aggregate data (Y=count).

That should not make a difference. A Poisson likelihood for individual patient data, for the aggregate data and for an exponential time-to-first event model should be mathematically equivalent.
